# LightGBMError: b'Check failed: config->bagging_freq > 0 && config->bagging_fraction < 1.0f && config->bagging_fraction > 0.0f

Tags: python, random-forest, lightgbm

Working with lightGBM on Python and as it doesn't have enough documentation, I am unable to tackle this issue since a while. Please help me out with these few questions if anyone with lgb experience available here.

1. lgb.cv doesn't work when having a continuous target variable. Why?
2. When having objective "regression" can I have boosting_type as "rf" (random Forest)? This [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1246) opened here on the library kinda confirms that I can. Thoughts?
3. Below is the piece of code that works completely fine if I replace the "rf" parameter with "gbdt"

   ```
   params = {
           "objective" : "regression", "metric" : "rmse",
           "num_leaves" : 150, "learning_rate" : 0.05,
           "bagging_fraction" : 0.6, "feature_fraction" : 0.7,
           "bagging_frequency" : 1, "bagging_seed" : 2018,
           "verbosity" : -1, 'max_depth':-1,
           "min_child_samples":20, "boosting":"rf"}

   model = lgb.train(params, lgtrain, 1000, valid_sets=[lgval],
           early_stopping_rounds=20, verbose_eval=20, evals_result=evals_result)
   ```

**On having random forest boosting method, I get the following error -**

```
LightGBMError: b'Check failed: config->bagging_freq > 0 && config->bagging_fraction < 1.0f && config->bagging_fraction > 0.0f at /home/travis/build/Microsoft/LightGBM/python-package/compile/src/boosting/rf.hpp, line 29 .\n'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774825/python-lightgbm-cross-validation-how-to-use-lightgbm-cv-for-regression

Adding stratified=False works. I guess this link here answers my first question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error suggests, the code fails because the check does not pass. The reason is very simple- the name of the frequency variable is `bagging_freq`  instead of `bagging_frequency`.

And you have already found the right answer to the first question about `lgb.cv` configuration for regression.

Comment: That worked. bagging_frequency works when having 'gdbt' as boosting type. Strange.